# Shared border for all node's children

Tags: java, swing, jtree

What is the easiest way to create one common border for all children of a given node?

I have a code that result you can see on the first picture (created my own TreeRenderer, border added in *getTreeCellRendererComponent* method). On the second one there is a result that I wish to achieve.

[image: Every child has its own border]
1.

[image: One border for all children]
2.

Comment: +1 but please to search  [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm),  [maybe here](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/index.html)